# QGIS Atlas page order problem

Tags: qgis, printing, atlas

I am using QGIS Atlas to export my work into PDFs. I have created a support polygon layer, which contain rectangles and I use this layer as coverage layer in QGIS atlas. My problem is that I don't know how the pagenumbers work. It change the page order when I update a feature in the coverage layer. For that reason I activated the sort by option, and used the autoincrement id of the coverage layer, but nothing had happened. It looks like the atlas is using kind of time metadata for page numbering. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Have you created an integer field containing the desired page number per feature? Which QGIS version? If the issue only appears with autoincrement fields (which data source?) and it's a current QGIS version, should be reported as bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like the autoincrement field caused the proble. I created a new integer field for pagenumbers and that work well. If you add your comment as answer I'll accept as solution. (I used qgis Lyon, and las palmas versions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that the issue only appears with autoincrement fields. Try creating an integer field containing the desired page number.

If this is an issue in the latest QGIS version, it should be reported as bug.

Comment: I'm using QGIS 3.0.2 and have a similar problem.  I added a field to the controlling layer which contains the map number.  So there are 2 fields in the table, fid which was system created as a unique key, and id which I created.  I use the expression concat('Map No ', $id) but QGIS insists on replacing id with the value in fid.

Comment: Just found that if I make the expression concat('Map No ', id) it works.  The $ before id seems to have been the problem.  I've a bit to learn obviously.